# SQL to filter out some data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table: `mydata`

```
id    content   name
1     1         a
2     2         b
3     2         c
4     13        hhh
5     13        yyyy
6     7         wwww
7     13        iiii
8     7         nnnn
9     8         oooo
```

It will look at "content" field. If the same value inside "content" show up more than one time, it will display out. Here is final result

```
id    content   name
2     2         b
3     2         c
6     7         wwww
8     7         nnnn
4     13        hhh
5     13        yyyy
7     13        iiii
```

Thus how to write this SQL?

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from myData
where content in (
  select content
  from myData
  group by content
  having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: LOL. Exactly the same answer at exactly the same time :)  I'll let you have it since you have less rep.

Comment: It doesn't work. It displays following error message: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @andy: What sql database engine are you using?  You should always include that in your tags because it makes a difference.

Comment: I use MySQL with MyISAM. It shows an error message when I use your sql statement.